# Podio API - Java - Attaching files to existing items

Tags: java, podio

I've been searching high and low for any information on this but I haven't found anything useful so far. I'm relatively new to the podio API and I'm trying to upload/attach a file I create in my program to a specific item in a specific app. I've successfully uploaded the file to the API and I've added it to the specific item's list of files however it doesn't 'stick'/update to have any permanence. At the end of the method I can call getFiles() and the file will be there however the file is not visible on podio and if i call getFiles() any other time it won't be there. Here's my code:

```
public static void uploadTimeSheet(File timeSheet){
    FileAPI fileApi = apiFactory.getAPI(FileAPI.class);
    int fileId = fileApi.uploadFile(timeSheet.getName(), timeSheet);
    com.podio.file.File timeSheetUploaded = fileApi.getFile(fileId);
    List<com.podio.file.File> files = new ArrayList<com.podio.file.File>();
    files = userItem.getFiles();
    files.add(timeSheetUploaded);
    userItem.setFiles(files);
}
```

userItem is the specific Item I want to upload the file to. I'm by no means an experienced coder but it seems to me that by calling setFiles(files) i only update a local version of the item userItem? If that's the case then how can I update podio's version of userItem with my own? And if i completely barking up the wrong tree where have I gone wrong? I've been searching for methods which update items but they only seems to be for updating fields/field values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach file method is not available in Java SDK unfortunately. You can use other SDKs such as ruby

```
 # Attach a file to an existing reference
    # @see https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/attach-file-22518
    def attach(id, ref_type, ref_id)
      Podio.connection.post do |req|
        req.url "/file/#{id}/attach"
        req.body = {:ref_type => ref_type, :ref_id => ref_id}
      end
    end
```

If you really wanna work in JAVA SDK, I will update JAVA SDK corresponding method or there is a work around you can use updateItem to update a file to an existing item.

```
public void updateItemFieldValues(int itemId, int fieldId,
            List<Map<String, Object>> values, boolean silent, boolean hook) {
        getResourceFactory()
                .getApiResource("/item/" + itemId + "/value/" + fieldId)
                .queryParam("silent", silent ? "1" : "0")
                .queryParam("hook", hook ? "1" : "0")
                .entity(values, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).put();
    }
}
```

the above the file ID have to be derived from the below method  [image]

Let me know it helps.

Comment: I've been working on the work around today and I reckon I've got it workable so thank you for that! Unfortunately attaching files to an existing item is a small but important part of an already big project so it has to be Java. If the attachFile method could be added in the Java API then brilliant but it looks like it's not necessary for my program to run. Just one question, as the files attached using the work around are not 'officially' attached, their IDs are just stored, is there some kind of time or quantity limit to be aware of or is it certain they won't be removed from the system?

Answer (score 1):

Any update to the Item will create a version for you, so you don't have to create. You can get the version or revert to version with methods of below link.

https://developers.podio.com/doc/items

Is your question is about dealing with files of the items, specify them accordingly, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you clarify what you mean? Using https://developers.podio.com/doc/items (and the java api documentation) I have successfully uploaded the file to the API (https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/upload-file-1004361), added that file to the list of files attached to the item I want to attach the item to, and set this new updated list as the item's files. These last two I have done using the Java documentation in the API as the Java API seems to be missing methods such as https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/attach-file-22518 . Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: Just to clarify using the above method of attaching files to pre-existing items has not brought me success. As I think you have said in your reply I have created a local version of the item which contains the file I wish it to contain. My issue is then how to make that local version the version on podio so the item is permantly uploaded to the given item and can be found manually on podio. Thanks once again!